# Vine identification please

Tags: identification, vines

I need to find out what type of vine this is because it is growing on a fence that my cats have access to from the inside. I don't want to be growing anything that is poisonous to cats. There are two types of leaves on the same plant it seems and it grows so fast you can almost see it. I live in northeast Tennessee. I planted some wildflowers but I feel like this is a weed.[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The fast growth and the variability of the leaf shape indicate the Kudzu vine ([*Pueraria montana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudzu)). Check this by feeling the surface of the leaf; Kudzu will feel slightly hairy. Generally the young leaves have a single part, as the vine gets older and more vigorous they become lobed and have 3 parts. Some parts of the plant are considered edible, others such as root and other woody parts toxic. The fast growth makes it an invasive plant, something whose growth you will need to monitor carefully.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why that never occurred to me!